# How to redirect actions to be "mock" controllers in Zend?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, zend-framework2

I'm working on a site where the IndexController holds some pages like "about", "contact" and etc. I'd like for either Zend or a .htacess config to redirect /about to /index/about, but without URL re-writing (or at least, have it be transparent to the user).

So it'd perform something like this:

mysite.com/about => mysite/index/about (w/o showing said URI to the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything special to do that, ZF2 is perfectly equipped to handle custom routes. The [ZF2 tutorial by Akrabat](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2-tutorial/) shows it all well. You'll end up doing something like this in your config:

```
'Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStack' => array(
    'parameters' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'about' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                        'action'     => 'about',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
)
```

Of course you can also automatize these things by extending the ActionController or by writing a Controller Plugin.

Comment: I'd rather use a solution that would avoid inventing a new controller, these seems to be quite efficient!

I'll try it now.

Comment: Wait, in which config? Not my application/configs/application.ini, no?

Comment: In module\Application\config\module.config.php. As I said, work through the Akrabat tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Using the new Service Manager config:

```
'controller' => array(
    'classes' => array(
        'index_controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
'routes' => array(

    'activities_list' => array(
        'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
            'route' => '/about', <- The requested URL
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'index_controller', <- What will process the request
                'action'     => 'about',
            ),
        ),
    ),

), // End of routes
), // End of router
```

Comment: The new service manager you refer to would be Zend_ServiceManager, no? If I wanted to place this in my IndexController::init() method, how would it look?

Also, you know of any documentation that further explains this? I've found mostly boilerplate code.

Comment: The following configure goes to /module/myModule/config/module.config.php. In the controller you can: $this->getServiceLocator() to get the Service Manager

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to the .htaccess file in your document root in somewhere appropriate:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about(.*)$ /index/about$1 [L]
```

Comment: I would very much advice against solving this problem via Apache!